# VBS - csv to text files

Tags: vbscript

I need a script to create a empty text file for each row in my csv file.

My csv file has 3 columns of data...

```
Along Came Polly,2003,192
American Beauty,1999,146
American Cousins,2007,286
An American Crime,2007,179
```

I want to create a empty text file named for each row and formatted as....

```
Along Came Polly (2003) Slot 192.txt
American Beauty (1999) Slot 146.txt
American Cousins (2007) Slot 286.txt
An American Crime (2007) Slot 179.txt
```

Can someone help me with this as I have no vb experience.

Thank you,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

This is what you might be looking for

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO, objTextFile, strFileLine,objFile,strFileName



' Create the File System Object
 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


 Set objTextFile=objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Documents and Settings\amolc\Desktop\SO\Sample.csv")  ''Mention Path of your CSV file here 


 Do Until objTextFile.atEndOfStream
     strFileLine =objTextFile.ReadLine
     strFileLine =Split(strFileLine,",")
     strFileName=strFileLine(0)&" ("&strFileLine(1)&") "&"Slot "&strFileLine(2)&".txt"
     Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Documents and Settings\amolc\Desktop\SO\"&strFileName)  ''Hardcoded path is the location where you can store your text file
Loop
```